# How can I check if index 0 matches index 1 in a list? for example, checking if a username matches the given password, hope that makes sense

Tags: python

```
database=[['username1','password1'],['username2','password2']]

 def check_match():
  check_username()
  check_password() 
  for pair in database:
    if check_username==pair[0]:
      if check_password==pair[1]:
        print('login succesful!')
        return
  else:
    print('login failed')
    return
```

This is the code I have currently to check if index 0 of a list matches index 1 of the same list, It's not working though. `check_username()` and `check_password()` hold the contents of a list based on user input.

Comment: define "it's not working" please. Add a bunch of `print()` into your code to give you idea what goes wrong, and when you have more details, share them.

Comment: `check_username()` and `check_password()` seem to be functions (you call them in the first two lines of `check_match()`) so of course they won't match your string entries. Have you forgotten to store the response from calling them into local variables which would you use to check against your database?

Comment: check_username is a function? were have you assigned its value?

Comment: what do check_username() function return?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I called the incorrect functions in the given function, that's my bad, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer. You can modify it accordingly but i made it to satisfy the basic needs;

```
database=[['username1','password1'],['username2','password2']]

username = 'username1'
password = 'password2'


def login(username, password):
    for i in range(len(database)):
        if username == database[i][0] and password == database[i][1]:
            print("login successfull")
            return
    print("invalid credentials")


login(username, password)
```

`username` and `password` can be taken from the user.